# Gulp connect-livereload doesnt work with gzip

Tags: gzip, gulp, httpserver

Recently i have added the gulp-gzip task to my gulp script pipeline, that also has a livereload to refresh the browser when any file changes.

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  connect.server({ port: 8080, root: 'public/', livereload: true });
});
```

The reload works fine but the server doesnt serve the gziped files fine. 
In the browser network it appears the files content compressed:
[image]
If i launch a simple-http-server in the path the gz files are served correctly. It is possible to tune the gulp-connect server to solve de gz issue?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, instead of gzipping your files and then delivering them from the server, you should, as you said, tune the gulp-connect server to deliver the files compressing them beforehand. For this, you can use the `middleware` configuration attribute in the gulp-connect server to provide the gzip extension as it is used in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gcpantazis/91ba3e8d89b78ac5bed7) and, of course, you will need to add the `connect-gzip`dependency to your project. Hope it helps!